# Loading jquery UI in FF 11 give error:: "TypeError: a is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox-addon

I am using jquery(ui as well) in my ff extension. All is working fine till ff 10.

```
var loader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);

loader.loadSubScript("chrome://myext/content/js/jquery-1.7.2.js",wnd);

var jQ = wnd.jQuery.noConflict(true);
  try {
          loader.loadSubScript("chrome://myext/content/js/jquery.ui.core.min.js", jQ);
  } catch (Except){
    alert(Except.toString());
  }
```

In FF 11 this code is not working.
As per the above code, I am trying to load the jquery and then loading the jquery ui libs.
Jquery is getting loaded but it doesn't load the "chrome://myext/content/js/jquery.ui.core.min.js" and give error "TypeError: a is undefined"

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Do you get a better error loading the non-minified version? Why are you passing the jQuery object into the call - would that require changes to the UI code to work? I assume you mean you want the jQuery parameter it uses in the wrapping function call to be your jQ but I'd be surprised if that was the syntax to do it. Does it work if you load it into `wnd`?

Comment: No It doesn't work using wnd.

Comment: Also it is a standard way to load jquery in extension. http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2105087

Comment: Yes, please try the non-minified version. Also replace `alert()` by `Components.utils.reportError(Except)` - you will see the proper error message and line number in Error Console, then you (and us) won't need to guess.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I have a similar problem. My error message is "Type Error: $ is undefined". Firefox version 8.0. and Components.utils.reportError(Except) prints nothing in Error Console. I'm trying to load jquery.hoverIntent.js downloaded from [here](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Comment: @xralf: I wish I could downvote a comment. I hate people saying "I have a similar problem" without understanding what the original problem is (because nobody can understand it without proper information).

Comment: @WladimirPalant The conditions are very similar, the goal is similar and the error is similar. I don't understand it too, that's why I supported this question.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error, but putting loadSubScript in this position it worked for me:

```
//load jQuery

var loader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"]
                       .getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);
loader.loadSubScript("chrome://myext/content/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js",context);
var jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);

if( typeof(jQuery.fn._init) == 'undefined') { jQuery.fn._init = jQuery.fn.init; }

var $ = function(selector,context){ return new jQuery.fn.init(selector,context||myext.doc); };
$.fn = $.prototype = jQuery.fn;

myext.jQuery = jQuery;
myext.$ = $;

loader.loadSubScript("chrome://myext/content/lib/jquery.tablesorter.js",jQuery);
```

Comment: So, Dinesh position of *loadSubScript* is wrong? Why it should be another way and how would you change it?

Comment: Well, it's not totally clear to me, but: when I had the error ("Type Error: $ is undefined"), row with _loadSubScript_ was right below the one with _var jQuery_. I've moved it after my local definitions of $, and then it worked. I don't have a deep knowledge of how _loadSubScript_ works and I don't know how scope is managed by it, but it seems that putting that row after $ declarations adds $ to the plugin's scope. Maybe someone more expert than me will clarify this aspect, but I can tell you that it's now working... and it could be the same for Dinesh, even with a different plugin.

Comment: Hi, I've tried with jquery UI and it doesn't work... so my solution is not good in this case.