# jQuery.hoverIntent.js in Firefox extension does not load

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, hoverintent

According to [this](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2105087) guide
I tried to load *JQuery* to my *Firefox* extension.

```
var Myext = {

  loadJQuery: function(wnd) {
      var loader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);
      loader.loadSubScript("chrome://myext/content/jquery-1.7.2.min.js", wnd);
      var jQuery = wnd.jQuery.noConflict(true);
      try {
        loader.loadSubScript("chrome://myext/content/jquery.hoverIntent.js", jQuery);
      catch (Except) {
        alert(Except.toString());
      }
      return jQuery;
  },

  onLoad: function(e) {
    Myext.jQuery = Myext.loadJQuery(window);
  },

  showDialog: function(e) {
    var $ = Myext.jQuery;
    /* JQuery code */
  }

}

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) { Myext.onLoad(e); }, false);
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) { Myext.showDialog(e); }, false);
```

Loader has a problem to load `jquery.hoverIntent.js`. I downloaded it [here](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

error message: `"Type Error: $ is undefined"`

Comment: jQuery.noConflict(); var doc = window.content.document;
alert(jQuery("body", doc).html());

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `.dialog()` you need to include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) library also. Put the next line right after you loaded the jQuery library:

```
loader.loadSubScript("chrome://myext/content/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js", wnd);
```

The last jQuery UI library you can download from [here](http://jqueryui.com/download).

Comment: I have done it but still can't see the dialog. I copied only the file `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js` to `myext/content` directory.

Comment: It seems that nothing from JQuery works. When I replace dialog function with `$("a").click(function() {
       alert("Hello world!");
     });` I can't see message when clicking on links.

Comment: Where do you have `<div id="#dialog">text</div>`? It should be part of the DOM of the html page in the tab. Also you probably need to add smth. like `$("#dialog", gBrowser.contentDocument).dialog()` ... Check also Error Console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`) and don't forget to restart Firefox after every changes you made.

Comment: I removed the code with dialog and try only the code from my previous comment. Could I open the dialog without having an element with `#dialog` id? I'd like to open it on event.

Comment: the code `var loader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubscriptLoader);` is not executed at all.

Comment: OK there was an error (sorry for my blind eyes) `mozIJSSubScript` , but there is still something wrong.

Comment: @xraf Did you include that file in your default XUL file (which you specified in `chrome.manifest`? [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#Example_chrome_manifest)

Comment: Yes, functions without jquery work. `jquery` was loaded but there are problems with loading `jquery-ui` and `jquery-hover-intent` now.

Comment: Why do you have `jQuery` as the `targetObj` parameter when you load `jquery-hover-intent`?

Comment: Because it is [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2105087). I'm beginning with jquery.

Comment: For me everything looks OK then, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906899/loading-jquery-ui-in-ff-11-give-error-typeerror-a-is-undefined). Probably, you have the same problem with jQuery UI

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to change the question a little because I have to overcome the error I've stuck. You advised me to download jquery-ui, which was needed too for the code to work. I will probably ask on the dialogs in another question, but I have to first overcome this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
onLoad: function(e) {
    Myext.jQuery = Myext.loadJQuery(window);
  },
```

Shouldn't be?

```
onLoad: function(e) {
    Myext.jQuery = loadJQuery(window);
  },
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't help. I think, you should refer to namespace.